# Identify the grid particles belong to

Tags: python, pytorch

A square box of size `10,000*10,000` has `10,00,000` particles distributed uniformly. The box is divided into grids, each of size `100*100`. There are `10,000` grids in total. At every time-step (for a total of `2016` steps), I would like to identify the grid to which a particle belongs. Is there an efficient way to implement this in python? My implementation is as below and currently takes approximately 83s for one run.

```
import numpy as np
import time
start=time.time()
# Size of the layout
Layout = np.array([0,10000])
# Total Number of particles
Population = 1000000
# Array to hold the cell number
cell_number = np.zeros((Population),dtype=np.int32)
# Limits of each cell
boundaries = np.arange(0,10100,step=100)
cell_boundaries = np.dstack((boundaries[0:100],boundaries[1:101]))
# Position of Particles
points = np.random.uniform(0,Layout[1],size = (Population,2))
# Generating a list with the x,y boundaries of each cell in the grid
x = []
limit_list = cell_boundaries
for i in range(0,Layout[1]//100):
    for j in range(0,Layout[1]//100):
        x.append([limit_list[0][i,0],limit_list[0][i,1],limit_list[0][j,0],limit_list[0][j,1]])  
# Identifying the cell to which the particles belong
i=0
for y in (x):
  cell_number[(points[:,1]>y[0])&(points[:,1]<y[1])&(points[:,0]>y[2])&(points[:,0]<y[3])]=i 
  i+=1
print(time.time()-start)
```

Comment: Please provide an inefficient way to implement this in Python, then you will most likely receive some help!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, the question has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your code. You seem to be accumulating the `i` variable globally. While it should be accumulated on a *per* cell basis, correct? Something like `cell_number[???] += 1`, maybe?

Anyhow, the way I see is from a different perspective. You could start by assigning each point a cell id. Then inverse the resulting array with a kind of [counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) function. I have implemented the following in PyTorch, you will most likely find equivalent utilities in *Numpy*.

The conversion from 2-point coordinates to cell ids corresponds to applying floor on the coordinates then unfolding them according to your grid's width.

```
>>> p = torch.from_numpy(points).floor()
>>> p_unfold = p[:, 0]*10000 + p[:, 1]
```

Then you can "inverse" the statistics, *i.e.* find out how many particles there are in each respective cell based on the cell ids. This can be done using PyTorch histogram's counter [`torch.histc`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.histc.html):

```
>>> torch.histc(p_unfold, bins=Population)
```